# classification-error resolved by shifting index, why?

Tags: matlab, parfor

I wish to use `parfor` for a nested loop, I have made an example showing my structure:

```
temp_vars  = 1:10;
global_arr = zeros(10,10);

parfor i=0:9
    for j=0:9 
        constant_var = temp_vars(i+1);
        global_arr(i+1, j+1) = i*j*constant_var;
    end
end
```

MATLAB gives me the error: `Error: The variable global_arr in a parfor cannot be classified.`.

However, if I change the values of `i` and `j` to `1..10` instead of `0..9`, then it magically works well. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reference `global_arr` using relative indices instead of absolute ones (i.e. `i+1` instead of `i`). When you use parallel `for`, each 'slice' of `global_arr` is computed independently on it's position in the loop, and relative indices implies dependent position, which is prohibited.

Try this instead:

```
parfor i = 1:10;
    for j = 1:10;
        constant_var = temp_vars(i);
        global_arr(i, j) = (i-1)*(j-1)*constant_var;
    end
end
```

More precisely, only the first index within the `parfor` loop can depend on the loop iterator, all the others are treated as constant. So you can use `i` in a relative way, but not `j`:

```
parfor i = 0:9;
    for j = 1:10;
        constant_var = temp_vars(i+1);
        global_arr(i+1,j) = i*(j-1)*constant_var;
    end
end
```

[From MATLAB doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html?searchHighlight=sliced%20variables):

> When you use other variables along with the loop variable to index an
>   array, you cannot set these variables inside the loop. In effect, such
>   variables are constant over the execution of the entire parfor
>   statement. You cannot combine the loop variable with itself to form an
>   index expression.

Comment: Say my variable `temp_vars` is much longer and I need to use more complicated indicices that cannot be resolved by simply shifting from `0..9` to `1..10`, e.g. `constant_var = temp_vars(10 + 100*j + 200*i);`. Does this imply that I cannot use `parfor`?

Comment: You can use it, but make a list of the indices to be given to `temp_vars` as function of `i` and `j` before the loop, and then make an absolute reference to them. Something like `temp_vars_ind (i,j)= 10 + 100*j + 200*i` outside the loop, and then `temp_vars(temp_vars_ind (i,j))`  in the loop.

Comment: Would it be an OK solution to alternatively make an anonomous function `ind = @(i,j) 10 + 100*j + 200*i` and then call `temp_vars( ind(i,j) )`?

Comment: in the case of `temp_vars` you don't need all this, because you don't change it, just retrieve elements from it, so you _can_ use relative indicies.

Comment: I'm sorry for any misleading, but in any way, you cannot use anything other then simple index like `i` or a constant, when you assign to some variable, so `global_arr(ind(i), ind(j) = ...` is forbidden.

Comment: Thanks. I think the anonomous function is a nice idea, this way I can also get arrays returned, e.g., `ind = @(i,j) 10 + 100*j + 200*i + 1:1000`